# For a standard normal distribution with mean = 0, SD = 1 why is P(N=0)=0?

Tags: probability-theory

A friend who's a grad student in numerical optimization posed this question to me and I said "well obviously because since it's a continuous distribution the number of values in the range is infinite." Then he noted that, though that's true doesn't it create a contradiction because the probability should be higher at the mean, but it's equal every as in 0 at any point. This is a good point, it's 0 at any point in a continuous distribution and if you sum up every point to get the total probability(I know this isn't how you do it with a PDF, but supposedly this should also get the total probability yes?) it's be 0*$\infty$=0, but then the total probability should add up to 1?

Comment: A classic issue is continuous statistics:  The probability of finding any particular *exact* number (such as $0$) is always $0$, even though when one selects one always gets *some* value.  Finite probabilities require integrating over a finite range of values, no matter how small that range might be.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Superb explanation !